# Problema con gráfico Pie / Donut de Apexchart

Tags: css, charts, libreria, apex-chart

Llevo un par de días intentando solucionar este problema, pero hasta ahora no he logrado hallar la solución. El gráfico funciona correctamente cuando hay pocos datos, pero cuando hay muchos, el gráfico se reduce para dar espacio a las etiquetas (legends) debajo del gráfico. Esto hace que la estructura que quiero que siempre sea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**He intentado:**

- Configurar el ancho y la altura en las opciones del 'chart', 'legend' y 'size' del donut
- Forzar con CSS, pero no parece tener ningún efecto.
- Usar la propiedad 'floating' de legend, pero las etiquetas legends se esconden en el contenedor del chart como si hubiese overflow: hidden
- Jugar con la propiedad 'responsive', pero el gráfico sigue encogiéndose por la cantidad de etiquetas legends.
- Sé que he probado otras opciones pero sigo sin tener éxito.

Por favor, adjunto un [link Codepen](https://codepen.io/soyluisarrieta/pen/bGxrBoG?editors=1010) para quien pueda ayudarme. Si hay algún detalle que necesiten, por supuesto pueden solicitarlo.

Comment: No entiendo porque no puedo replicarlo en mi PC. Puedes poner el código que usas en tu PC? Agregué la librería, el script y todo y no me dibuja la grafica.

Comment: Si se renderiza en codepen significa que está bien.

Comment: No te preocupes, era porque en codepen ya lo había resuelto pero quería dar una respuesta ya probada en mi PC porque siempre lo hago así pero déjalo. Igual deberías hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporcionar un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Ya veo, te agradezco la sugerencia y los enlaces. ¿Podrías proporcionarme la solución por favor?